# How to upload a file in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: rest, xamarin, file-upload, plugins, xamarin.forms

I need to upload a `.PDF` and/or `.JPG` file through a communication API with a `POST` method from Xamarin Forms with .NET Standard. For this I will be supported by a plugin that can open the camera and the gallery in this case I occupy `Xam.Plugin.Media`, but in the case of PDFs I can not open the file manager of the phone (where the files are saved)

The questions are:

1. In what plugin can I help to send PDF files? (That allows the user to select a file from the file manager independent of the operating system)
2. To send the PDF file through the API REST, do I need to transform it to an array of bytes? (I do the same in the case of photography)

Comment: File.ReadAllBytes() will return the contents of any file as a byte[].  Whether or not this is required by your API is something you need to determine by reading the docs or asking the developer.

Comment: Regarding how to access my file manager in DROID and IOS that suggests? @Jason

Comment: https://github.com/Studyxnet/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows

Comment: You have already answered my two questions, I should propose an answer @Jason

Comment: You should first turn your file into a byte[] and then use MultiPartDataFormContent to upload it. This is answered in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20319886/http-multipartformdatacontent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [File Picker](https://github.com/Studyxnet/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows) plugin for Xamarin

File.ReadAllBytes() will return the contents of any file as a byte[]. Whether or not this is required by your API is something you need to determine by reading the docs or asking the developer.