# search for file Xamarin-Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have this task where I have to find a PDF or PNG file. What I have to do is similar to when you send a picture in Whatsapp where you can search in the device. If someone have some light !!
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check this post for images:
https://lalorosas.com/blog/xamarin-forms-selecting-image-from-the-gallery

Check this post for PDFs: [How to upload a file in Xamarin.Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53172779/how-to-upload-a-file-in-xamarin-forms)

Please, google it first this is a trivial question solved many times.

Cheers :)

Comment: Yes I've found this article, however I also need to upload PDF files.

Comment: Check this :) just typing in google: "upload file xamarin" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53172779/how-to-upload-a-file-in-xamarin-forms