# Read both key values and files from multipart from data post request in ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, multipartform-data

I have an endpoint that needs to accept a file upload and also some other information from the client request. With the following code I can upload the file successfully but can't seem to figure out how to read the other info.

I make a test request from Postman with the following form data:

> image -- myimage.jpg -- of type File
>
> email -- a@b.com     -- of type Text

The backend code looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SharePhoto()
{   
    try
    {
         var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
         var data  = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

         // this is how I get the image which I am succesfully passing to EmailService
         var item = (StreamContent)provider.Contents[0];
         using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
         {
             await item.CopyToAsync(stream);
             String emailAddress;
             EmailService.SendSharedPhoto(emailAddress, stream);
             return Request.CreateResponse();
         }               
     }
     catch
     {
        // do stuff
     }
}
```

In this example I am able to access `provider.Contents[1]` but can't seem to be able to get the value from it into `emailAddress`. I'm thinking it may be possible to use the same trick as the `await item.CopyToASync(stream)` from the image upload, but I'm hoping I can get a simpler solution to that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I just barely answered a very similar question to this yesterday. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079917/submitting-file-and-json-data-to-webapi-from-httpclient/31096835#31096835) complete with sample controller code.

Answer (score 0):

The method I ended up using is:

If the form elements are strings (and it worked for me since the mobiel frontend took responsability for input data) you can do this:

```
var streamContent = (StreamContent)provider.Contents[1];
var memStream = new MemoryStream();
await streamContent.CopyToAsync(memStream);
var actualString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(x.ToArray());
```

If however the field needs to represent a collection of items, like for example the email list: ["a@b.com", "x@c.com"], etc a JavaScriptSerializer can be user, like so:

```
var streamContent = (StreamContent)provider.Contents[1];
var emailAddresses = await str.ReadAsStringAsync();
var jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var deserializedData = jsSerializer.Deserialize<string[]>(emailAddresses);
```

Note that this is nowhere near safe, though it is few lines of code and happens to work.