# How to post model and file in API controller using postman?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, postman

I am working on a [Web API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET#Extension) project and I'm unable to post both model and file simultaneously at a time. Postman throws an exception:

> System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException"

How can I fix this problem?

My code is looking like:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Appeal")]
public IHttpActionResult SaveAppeal(AppealModel model)
{
    try
    {
        var file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0 ?
        HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0] : null;

        var AppealResponses = _ContactService.SaveAppeals(model);
        return Ok(new { AppealResponses });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _log.ErrorFormat("Error in AppealResponses. Error:{0}", ex.Message);
        _log.Error(ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post example of code yoy are us8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submitting File and Json data to webapi from HttpClient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079917/submitting-file-and-json-data-to-webapi-from-httpclient)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postman have you set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` ?

Like this `Content-Type: application/json`
That should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31096835/1152738) with server side sample code.

Then in Postman, do a raw post and you can select your file and set your headers as needed.