# Send Json as body and file webrequest

Tags: c#, json, httpwebrequest

How to send both body and also a file?

From the API Guide: `"Upload Requests are submitted with multiple parts: body (request) and file buffer (file)."`

I know how to send only a Json as body, but I need now to seng Json as body and also a file.

My code looks something like:

```
            const string WEBSERVICE_URL = "https://myurl.com";
            var webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(WEBSERVICE_URL);
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data;boundary=12345678912345678912345678";
            webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization:7786FFFGFDDDP");
```

And:

```
      string json="{"\some json"\ :\"here\" }"
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {

            streamWriter.Write(json);             
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
        }
```

But how to send both file and body together? I mean I want also to upload some file wih path `@c:\\myFile.txt`

Comment: You want to send some file with each file path or some file with one parameter as a path?

Comment: I want to upload to the server some file, and also to send a body in a json format

Comment: probably this question help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data

Comment: This explains how to upload a file, but how to to upload a file and also a json string?

Comment: can use HttpClient instead of httpwebrequest?

Comment: @HasanFathi yes I can

Comment: use this Q&A https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079917/submitting-file-and-json-data-to-webapi-from-httpclient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to do this in a Xamarin application. Post an image to a web api with token based authentication. I made some changes in code to be posible use in a web application.

```
public async void SendFile()
{
    using (System.IO.FileStream stream = System.IO.File.Open(@"c:\file.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Open))
    {
        var content = new System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent();
        content.Add(new System.Net.Http.StreamContent(stream),
                "\"file\"",
                "Path to your file (ex: c:\temp\file.txt");

        await PostItemAsyncWithToken("url to post", content, "accessToken");
    }
}

public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool> PostItemAsyncWithToken(string url, System.Net.Http.HttpContent content, string accessToken)
{
    try
    {
        using (var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
            System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        throw new System.Exception("Error message", ex);
    }
}
```