# How to make multipart/mixed request containing nested HTTP requests

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient, .net-standard

I am trying to implement creating a multipart request where each part is a HTTP request

To see what I mean here's for example how this Google API works: https://cloud.google.com/dns/api/batch#example (I don't use that API, it's just an example)

I've seen examples using `MultipartFormDataContent` but I don't understand how to create each part"

```
--====1340674896===
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: 1111

POST /contacts/479038 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json

{ "SomeData" : 1 }
```

The content of each part is I think the serialized string of a request:

```
GET /contacts/479038 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json

{ "SomeData" : 1 }
```

So how do I create this? I guess I need to get the serialized version of a `HttpRequestMessage`?
Can I just serialize `request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())`

In WebAPI I see there's this `HttpContentMessage` which takes a `HttpRequestMessage` and can serialize it:

```
var httpMessageContent = new HttpMessageContent(request);
var buffer = httpMessageContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

But I don't have this class available in .NETStandard

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18059588 https://stackoverflow.com/q/16416601

Comment: There is material for multipart/form but not for multipart/mixed. Stuck at same issue